# Display products from api not from database in magento

Tags: api, magento

is it possible to display products from a third party api instead of displaying from db.

Am doing a shopping cart project using magento.. i have nearly 40000 products in my db.
here i have one search from. if user search for the products, then i have to get the products from third party api and display it to the users. if user clicks add-to-cart button then only i have to check that product with existing products in db and update it and continue.

is it possible to do it? sry if i asked any silly questions.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible (you will have to override product collection class), but it will be VERY slow. More over the 3rd party API may have calls limit per day or so and this will make your site not working. I'd recommend you allow 3rd party to add products using Magento API or to make Magento getting products from the 3rd party API dayly (weekly/horly) and storing them in it's database.

Comment: thanx for u rly..i have already did that(calling api to add products). the prblem is there is more than 40 to 50 thousand records.. so it takes very long time to execute, as api products updated very often.